# How to access Windows on_screen keyboard accessory through Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pythoncard

I am creating a touch screen project through "Python Card". To fill data in a text box, can I bring the Windows on-screen keyboard to my program instead of creating a soft keyboard myself? 
I am trying to get the Windows on-screen keyboard using PyWin32, but it doesn't execute properly.
Are there better ways to get this keyboard functionality into my application?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
os.system("osk")
```

This will invoke the on screen keyboard, active for the window that invokes it.

Comment: By the way, it is preferable to use subprocess rather than os.system to invoke commands, because subprocess can easily deal with whitespaces in the command.